# Compile C++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to compile a simple application in linux.  My main.cpp looks something like

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Database.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Database * db = new Database();
    commandLineInterface(*db);
    return 0;
}
```

Where Database.h is my header and has a corresponding Database.cpp.  I get the following error when compiling:

```
me@ubuntu:~/code$ g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -o test
/tmp/ccf1PF28.o: In function `commandLineInterface(Database&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `Database::transducer(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x492): undefined reference to `Database::transducer(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x50c): undefined reference to `Database::transducer(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/tmp/ccf1PF28.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x721): undefined reference to `Database::Database()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Searches for something like this are all over the place as you can imagine.  Any suggestions on what I might be able to do to fix the problem?

Comment: I think we're gonna need to see the Database.(h|cpp) files, or at least `Database` class, and `commandLineInterface` interface/implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are *linker* errors.  It is complaining because it is trying to produce the final executable, but it cannot, because it has no object code for `Database` functions (the compiler does not infer that the function definitions corresponding to `Database.h` live in `Database.cpp`).

Try this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp Database.cpp -o test
```

Alternatively:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -c -o main.o
g++ -std=c++0x Database.cpp -c -o Database.o
g++ Database.o main.o -o test
```

Comment: I suspected this but wasn't sure.  Now my database class has other includes and so on.  Surely there is a way to compile everything without having to type it in everytime?  Script or is there a g++ option?

Comment: @Pete -  you want a make file.  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html  Or use an IDE that will create one for your project.

Answer (score 2):

You refer to code from `Database.h` so you have to provide an implementation, either in a library or via an object file `Database.o` (or a source file `Database.cpp`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile `Database.cpp` as well, and link the two together.

This:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -o test
```

tries to compile `main.cpp` to a complete executable. Since the code in `Database.cpp` is never touched, you get linker errors (you call out into code that is never defined)

And this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp Database.cpp -o test
```

compiles both files into an executable

The final option:

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp Database.cpp -c
g++ main.o Database.o -o test
```

First compiles the two files to separate object fiels (.o), and then links them together into a single executable.

You may want to read up on how the compilation process in C++ works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -o test
```

try something like

```
g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp Database.cpp -o test
```

This should fix missing references in the linking process.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compile main.cpp without the Database source files. Include the Database object file in the g++ command and these functions will be resolved.

I can pretty much guarantee to you that this will become a pain fast. I recommend using make to manage compilation.