# help with insert on first BST

Tags: c++, g++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

EDIT there a small thing that I am missing!! the error is still there

So I am attempting to learn how to code my first BST, and it is hard.... I am already having trouble with just a few lines of codes. the problem is in the insert, but I have included everything so that I could get some feedback on my style/other errors.  I was suggested to use a pointer to pointer implementation, but we havent learned it yet, so I dont feel comfort/know how to code it yet. the

error is

```
[trinhc@cs1 Assignment_3]$ g++ movieList.cpp -o a.out
/tmp/ccLw6nsv.o: In function `main':
movieList.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `Tree::Tree()'
movieList.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `Tree::insert(int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the tree.h file

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Tree
{
 public:
  Tree();
  bool insert(int k, string s);

 private:
  struct Node
  {
    int key;
    string data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
  };
  Node* root;
  bool insert(Node*& root, int k, string s);
};

#endif
```

tree.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tree.h"
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Tree::Tree()
{
  root = NULL;
}

bool Tree::insert(int k, string s)
{
  return insert(root, k, s);
}

bool Tree::insert(Node*& current_root, int k, string s)
{
  if(root == NULL){
    current_root = new Node;
    current_root->key = k;
    current_root->data = s;
    current_root->left = NULL;
    current_root->right = NULL;
    return true;
  }
  else if (current_root->key == k)
    return false;
  else if (current_root->key > k)
    insert(current_root->left, k, s);
  else
    insert (current_root->right,k, s);
}
```

movieList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include "tree.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Tree test;
  test.insert(100, "blah");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't  `else if (root == k)` in insert be `else if (root->key == k)`.

Comment: @Dan yes it should, thanks for pointing that out, the problem is still there tho :/

Comment: You should post requests for code reviews at http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: thanks Emile, i didnt there was a site for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied some of your code and this is working fine for me:

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include "tree.h"

    int main()
    {
      Tree test;
      test.insert(100, "blah");
      test.insert(50, "fifty");
      test.insert(110, "one hundred ten");
      return 0;
    }
```

Insert function:

```
bool Tree::insert(Node*& currentRoot, int k, string s)
{
  if(currentRoot == NULL){
    currentRoot = new Node;
    currentRoot->key = k;
    currentRoot->data = s;
    currentRoot->left = NULL;
    currentRoot->right = NULL;
    return true;
  }
  else if (currentRoot->key == k)
    return false;
  else if (currentRoot->key > k)
    insert(currentRoot->left, k, s);
  else
    insert (currentRoot->right,k, s);
}
```

Other than that you have syntax errors all over the place.  I also changed the name because as someone pointed out there was a bit of a naming problem.  CurrentRoot makes sense because you are passing it the root of the left or right subtree on every recursion.

Comment: can u point our some of the syntax errors?? is it just the clashing of the name root??

Comment: Can u take a look again, i know my logic is sound, but theres something that F ing it up!!

Comment: @kingcong3 I dont mind helping you out but you need to be a bit more specific.  We don't need all of your code including unimplemented stuff.  What are you trying to do that is not working?  The code I provided is properly inserting my test data.

Comment: @Pete i cleaned up the codes a bit so it is easier to read. it is still giving the error.  I am not sure what is wrong.  So can you comment on whether or not I should use pointer as a reference or not like others suggested?

Comment: @kingcong3 If I pass by reference, it works as it should as in my example code.  I am sure someone will jump all over me if I am wrong but it has to be passed by reference otherwise you won't be able to change the pointer which we have to do.  When currentRoot is NULL we assign it a pointer to a new Node.  If you don't pass by reference then you are changing only a copy of that pointer.

Comment: @Pete, the code in the post is current, and i added back the reference but the error is still there.  I am assuming that the problem is in the helper?? what is the correct way to use the helper?

Comment: @kingcong3 I dunno.  The error is in your movieList.cpp but I dont see any code for a movieList.cpp.

Comment: @Pete movieList is really just main, i just named it differently on here so just people know it is the main function that is doing everything

Comment: @kingcong3 The answer here explains it better than I could.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745903/compile-c-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

Tree test();  is not how define an object of class Test, This acutally declare function named test which returns Tree.

try

Tree test;
test.instert(100, "blah");
return 0;

Comment: Thanks, I called that at first, but I didnt know where the error came from so i started doubting myself and changed it

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points:

You need to change the name of your member variable root to something else– I'd recommend m_root, or my_root, or tree_root, or something of those sorts.  Right now you've got a little bit of a namespace clash in any function where you include root as an argument.  This will also let you keep track of which root you're referring to.

```
bool Tree::insert(Node*& root, int k, string s)
{
    if(root == NULL){
        root = new Node;
        root->key = k;
        root->data = s;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        return true;
    } else
        if (root == k) //Comparison between pointer and number.
            return false;
        else
            if (root->key > k)
                insert(root->left, k, s);
            else
                insert (root->right,k, s);
    }
```

You need to change root on the commented line to root->key.

Other than that, it looks like it'll work.

EDIT: Also, what the other guy said.  You declare an object as

```
TYPE name ()
```

if you are calling the default constructor (), so your code in your main function should be

```
Tree test;
test.insert(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it but theres still that error.  Can u take a look again??

Comment: You probably need to add a "using namespace std;" line to your main file.  It works fine on MacOS with GCC.  EDIT: Also, make sure you compile your class file (g++ -c tree.cpp -> g++ -c movielist.cpp -> g++ -o a.out movielist.o tree.o)

Comment: i think the problem is in my helper call, but i dont really know how to call it correctly

Comment: Ok, issue determined.  You're not compiling the tree class.  Instead of the "g++ movieList.cpp -o a.out" line, you need to do "g++ -c tree.cpp", and once that's done, "g++ -c movieList.cpp", then "g++ -o a.out movieList.o tree.o"

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add `tree.cpp` to your build command?

> [trinhc@cs1 Assignment_3]$ g++
>   movieList.cpp -o a.out

Would become

> [trinhc@cs1 Assignment_3]$ g++
>   tree.cpp movieList.cpp -o a.out